# Serving 2 different websites from the same IIS server on the same port

Tags: windows, iis, hostname, amazon-route53

I have 2 different websites:

- `mysite.com`
- `api.mysite.com`

I want to be able to serve both of these websites from the same webserver (same IP) and same port number.

I have followed [this document](https://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/), and created the following websites:

[image]

This is how the binding for `mysite.com` looks like:

[image]

And this is how the binding for `api.mysite.com` looks like:

[image]

Note that the only way I could define 2 sites using the same IP and Port was to use a Host name for one of them.

With the above settings, `mysite.com` works but `api.mysite.com` does not work. If I stop `mysite.com` from IIS, then `api.mysite.com` starts working.

The document that I used as a guide explains that I need to use **dnsmgmt.msc** to define a CNAME for api.mysite.com, but here is where I am confused. I am using AWS and I have defined 2 CNAME records for these websites in *Route 53*. Do I still need to define a CNAME record for one of these websites in Windows?

If not, then how would I tell IIS that request containing `api.mysite.com` should be sent to website having the `host name = api.mysite.com`?

### Update

The answer provided by Greg suggests that I would add mysite.com as Host name as well. If I follow this solution, how would I handle requests for `www.mysite.com`?

At the moment, any request for `mysite.com` is permanently redirected to `www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add mysite.com to the binding for that site to match the similar configuration for api.mysite.com

My guess is that the mysite.com one is matching the request condition for api.mysite.com (just port 80).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how should I handle `www.mysite.com`?  I have updated the question.

Comment: You don’t have a www.mysite.com configuration on your server, based on your screenshots.  Do you want both mysite.com and www.mysite.com to be the same site?  If so, you can just add a second binding for mysite.com that has www.mysite.com as a host name.